# Most efficent psycopg2 python escaping function

Tags: python, postgresql, python-3.x, psycopg2

I am currently trying to do a bulk insert with psycopy2 using (copy_from). Currently my code is below. I was hoping to get some advice on the most efficient escaping function and best practice for escaping values that contain restricted characters. I am using python3, the strings are coming mongodb.

The restricted characters are referenced here:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-copy.html
As taken from the documentation: 
"Backslash characters () can be used in the COPY data to quote data characters that might otherwise be taken as row or column delimiters. In particular, the following characters must be preceded by a backslash if they appear as part of a column value: backslash itself, newline, carriage return, and the current delimiter character."

```
def bulk_write(self, table, data, columns = None):
    with psycopg2.connect(database = self.database,
                          user = self.user,
                          host = self.host,
                          password = self.password) as conn:
      with conn.cursor() as cur:
        cur.execute("SET TIME ZONE 'PDT8PST';")
        cols_import = tuple(columns) if columns else None
        data_tsv = '\n'.join(['\t'.join(self.escape_copy_string(str(value)) for value in row) for row in data])
        with open("test","w") as f:
          f.write(data_tsv)
        cur.copy_from(io.StringIO(data_tsv), table, columns=cols_import, null="None")

   def escape_copy_string(self,s):
      s = s.replace("\\","\\\\").replace("\n","\\n").replace("\r","\\r").replace("\t","\\t")
      return s
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than hand-rolling it, I suggest using the `csv` module, and using `copy_from` in `csv` mode.

The data can't be that big if you're using list comprehensions to process it, either. You'll run out of RAM in a hurry doing that with anything big. Consider using a loop that writes each row as it goes instead.

Comment: The psycopg2 csv module or python's csv module? I am bulk loading the data in batches. Thanks!

Comment: @BradRuderman Python's `csv` module - as `psycopg2` has no `csv` submodule.

Comment: Thanks for the info, the CSV module was a good idea, however the looping through is not. If the data was too big then I should split and perform bulk inserts. Looping would be horrible on performance on initial inserts

Comment: @BradRuderman I was unclear. I meant that you could loop over the input and write each row to a `copy_from` stream - not do individual inserts.

Comment: PSA python's csv will not escape arrays correctly in pgsql's dialect

Comment: You can provide your own escaping format for postgres and even figure out something that both csv module and psycopg copy can understand, process, and not break. For now I settled on `DELIMITER(E'\t'), QUOTE(E'\''), ESCAPE(E'\\'), NULL(E'\x7f')` which roughly corresponds to `delimiter = "\t" quotechar = "'" doublequote = False escapechar = "\\" lineterminator = "\n" quoting = csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL null_char = '\x7f'` in csv dialect. Feel free to use your own values but beware of possible null-char mishandling in csv.

Comment: For example, one can use ascii control codes for separators and escaping thus allowing postgres to do pretty much anything with the values.

Comment: I don't understand what this answer means. How do you use copy_from in csv mode?

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of testing, I think using `replace` is the most efficient, at least comparing with a regex-based method:

```py
import re
import timeit

string_rep = {
    '\\': '\\\\',
    '\r': '\\r',
    '\n': '\\n',
    '\t': '\\t',
}
string_pattern = re.compile('|'.join(re.escape(key) for key in string_rep))


def escape_re_sub(text):
    return string_pattern.sub(lambda m: string_rep[m.group(0)], text)


def escape_str_replace(text):
    return (
        text.replace('\\', '\\\\')
        .replace('\n', '\\n')
        .replace('\r', '\\r')
        .replace('\t', '\\t')
    )


string_no_escape = 'This is some bit of text that has no strings to replace'

time_re_sub = timeit.Timer(lambda: escape_re_sub(string_no_escape)).autorange()
print('no escape sub    ', time_re_sub[0] / time_re_sub[1], 'iterations per second')

time_str_replace = timeit.Timer(lambda: escape_str_replace(string_no_escape)).autorange()
print('no escape replace', time_str_replace[0] / time_str_replace[1], 'iterations per second')

string_escape = 'This is some\r \\ bit of text \nthat has \t\t some things to \\t replace'

time_re_sub = timeit.Timer(lambda: escape_re_sub(string_escape)).autorange()
print('with escape sub    ', time_re_sub[0] / time_re_sub[1], 'iterations per second')

time_str_replace = timeit.Timer(lambda: escape_str_replace(string_escape)).autorange()
print('with escape replace', time_str_replace[0] / time_str_replace[1], 'iterations per second')
```

for me, output:

```
no escape sub     1088292.3082792824 iterations per second
no escape replace 1310796.652683603 iterations per second
with escape sub     251530.53121228397 iterations per second
with escape replace 913308.513839589 iterations per second
```

The difference appears particularly strong when there are characters to be escaped, but is present when escaping doesn't change the strings.